# How to read Parquet file without OOM using unequal chunks?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, chunks

I've large parquet file - using `pd.read_parquet` gives out of memory error, but for my problem it'd be enough to partition this file into multiple ones (I don't have read full file only relevant parts at the time, so at least in theory no OOM error). I've found solution with chunks of equal size, unfortunately my partition need to be more specific.

Let's assume that I've column `group_id` and I want to have separate parquet file for every unique value in `group_id`. This column look like this: 1,1, ...., 1, 2,2, ..., 2, 3,3,...,3, ...., n,n,...n, so there would be files: 1.parquet, 2.parquet, ... n.parquet , where n<10_000.
In every file there would be a few thousands of rows, but it'd varies across files e.g. for 1.parquet - 2521 rows, 2.parquet - 5209 rows etc. Note, that you can read `group_id` without out of memory error.

I wonder if it could be done in performant and concise way with `pandas`, `pyarrow.parquet` or any other way?